# How to restart while loop in Number Guessing Game

Tags: java, do-while

I'm having a problem with this code. 
The issue as I see it is that when the user runs the code and either guesses correctly or uses the max number of attempts, the while loop doesn't kick in and allow the game to restart.
My idea is to reset the counter (attempt) to zero and start again but I'm just getting the exit message with the overall score instead.

```
int guess = 0;
     int attempt = 0;
     int number = new Random().nextInt(1000) + 1;
     int scorePlayer = 0; int scoreComputer = 0;
     boolean repeat;

     System.out.println("Hello and welcome to the number guessing game.");
     System.out.println("Please guess a number between 1 and 1000");


    while(repeat == true){
         do{
             Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
             guess = Integer.parseInt(scan.nextLine());
             System.out.println("The number you guessed is "+guess);
             attempt++;

             if(guess == number){
                 System.out.println("Congratulations! You got it!!");
                 scorePlayer++;
                 System.out.println("Would you like to play again? [YES/NO]");
                 Scanner a = new Scanner(System.in);
                 String answer = a.nextLine().toUpperCase();
                 if (answer != "YES"){
                     //repeat = false;
                     System.out.println("Thank you for playing");
                     System.out.println("The final score is "+scorePlayer+" to you and "+scoreComputer+" to the server");
                     if (scorePlayer<scoreComputer){
                         System.out.println("Computer wins!");
                     }else{
                         System.out.println("You win!");
                     }break;
                 }else{
                     attempt = 0;
                 }
             }else if(guess < number){
                 System.out.println("That is incorrect, try a larger number");

             }else if(guess > number){
                 System.out.println("That is incorrect, try a smaller number");

             }if(attempt == 10 && guess != number){
                 System.out.println("That is the max number of guesses allowed");
                 System.out.println("The number you were looking for is "+number);
                 scoreComputer++;
                 System.out.println("Would you like to play again? [YES/NO]");
                 Scanner b = new Scanner(System.in);
                 String answer = b.nextLine().toUpperCase();
                 if (answer != "YES"){
                     //repeat = false;
                     System.out.println("Thank you for playing");
                     System.out.println("The final score is "+scorePlayer+" to you and "+scoreComputer+" to the server");
                     if (scorePlayer<scoreComputer){
                         System.out.println("Computer wins!");
                     }else{
                         System.out.println("You win!");
                     }break;
                 }else{
                     attempt = 0;
                 }
             }

         }while(guess != number || attempt == 0);
         repeat = false;
    }
```

Comment: Given then you fixed the compiler error  `while(repeat=true)`: You set `repeat` to `false` directly after the first inner `do-while`-loop has been finished. So what is the idea of the outer loop then? It runs exactly once.

Answer (score 1):

Single "=" is an assignment operator, simply change it to the double "==".

```
while(repeat == true)
```

Comment: That doesn't fix it, the issue wasn't caused by that typo so I think that the problem might lie elsewhere. The code doesn't allow the game to restart after the correct number is guessed or the user runs out of attempts

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what ugur said, you can simply do

```
while(repeat)
```

because repeat is a boolean variable (returning true or false)

Answer (score 0):

Check the last line in the outer loop you are setting `repeat=false`. So when you `break` from the inner loop, outer `while` check for repeat and it is false every time except the first.